# Use data in a frame to search another frame, then bind columns based on match

Tags: r

How do I: (1) systematically inspect all values in a column of data frame A, (2) find the additive inverse in the column of another data frame B, and (3) if I find the inverse, import that entire row of B (as new columns) into A? Example:

**A.frame**

```
##    Debit.Acct Debit.Proj Debit.Amt   
## 1      720240     023422    769.56  
## 2      720240     023422   3148.52    
## 3      720240     023422   6564.59
## 4      720240     023422   5844.30
```

**B.frame**

```
##       Period  Account  Project    Amount            Desc
## 2674  12      720240   122036    -769.56    023422DEPART
## 2675  12      720240   122035   -6564.59    021922DEPART
## 2676  12      720240   122035   -3148.52    023424DEPART
## 2677  12      720240   122035   -5855.20    023424DEPART
```

**Result I want, based on matching A.frame$Debit.Amt to B.frame$Amount:**

```
##    Debit.Acct Debit.Proj Debit.Amt  Account  Project    Amount         Desc
## 1      720240     023422    769.56   720240   122036   -769.56  023422DEPART
## 2      720240     023422   3148.52   720240   122035  -3148.52  023424DEPART
## 3      720240     023422   6564.59   720240   122035  -6564.59  021922DEPART
## 4      720240     023422   5844.30   NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1$Debit.Amt<--df1$Debit.Amt
merge(df1,df2,by.x="Debit.Amt",by.y="Amount",all.x=TRUE)
  Debit.Amt Debit.Acct Debit.Proj Period Account Project         Desc
1  -6564.59     720240      23422     12  720240  122035 021922DEPART
2  -5844.30     720240      23422     NA      NA      NA         <NA>
3  -3148.52     720240      23422     12  720240  122035 023424DEPART
4   -769.56     720240      23422     12  720240  122036 023422DEPART
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to R (and not much of a coder), and you saved me some grief. Your answer got me 99% of the way to my final Excel report.

Comment: Would you mind checking the answer as accepted if that was what you were looking for?